# How to design receipt panel in swing?

Tags: java, swing, printing

I have created general bill maker application on swing in which i've to print receipts as the output.
 Basically i am not able to understand how can show the list of items on the `panel` so that it is able to print?

I am using [`PrintUtilities.java`](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-Printing.html) to print
 the receipt panel.

What i am trying is to use a `JTable` for listing item details but if number of items is more than scrollpane viewport hieght than the rest of extra items are not shown and thus unable to print.

What can be the other way if i do not use JTable?
 Or a solution with JTable itself.

What i want is to extend my whole `dialog` vertically if no. of items exceeded rather than using autoscrolls in `JTable's` `scrollpane`.

I hope i am clear to my question.
[Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/41917866/dialog.PNG) is the **image** of what i am trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use Swing components as printed components.  Instead I'd build a PDF of the receipt and let the user print that.  Scrolling is just going to be a problem with printing actual swing components that isn't easy to handle.  This is a great PDF library:

http://pdfbox.apache.org/

Comment: Thanks for _pdf suggesstion_ but here I can't give users a pdf copy of there receipts..lol :D also my problem is with panel layout not with printing exactly.

Comment: Well you don't have to give them a PDF copy per se, but you could print the pdf for them and delete the file.  Because your trying to use Swing to design a printed document, instead of using a technology designed for that purpose ie pdf, you are running into issues about layout when it comes to printing on a sheet of paper.  This issue you describe is just one of the many issues you will encounter.  Use the right tool for the job.  Use PDF.